# Temporary value lifetime in async rust

Tags: rust

I am always wondering whether I need to bind variables into let or whether I can pass them directly into function calls.

Is the following code safe?

```
fn name() -> String {
    "John Doe"
}

async fn work() {
    some_async_fn(&name()).await;
}
```

Or should I instead:

```
async fn work() {
    let n = name()
    some_async_fn(&n).await;
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it be safe?

Comment: If it compiles and you didn't use `unsafe`, then it's safe.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly with @Jmb. Rust is not C++ where creating a reference to a temporary is always a bit risky. With Rust you should trust the compiler: if it says it is ok, just don't worry about it.

Comment: Thanks. Then I frankly don’t understand why the code compiles in the first place. 

I would expect that lifetime of the temporary value ends with the right brace ), but the reference to that value should be needed until .await, am I wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would expect that lifetime of the temporary value ends with the right brace `)`.

The lifetime of temporary values (like the return value from `name()`) extends until the end of the *statement*, not the end of the *sub-expression*. So the value from `name()` will not be destroyed until after the `.await`. If awaiting the function call was split into a separate statement, then the compiler will complain that the temporary value does not live long enough:

```
async fn work() {
    let some_fut = some_async_fn(&name());
    some_fut.await;
}
```

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
 --> src/lib.rs:8:35
  |
8 |     let some_fut = some_async_fn(&name());
  |                                   ^^^^^^ - temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
  |                                   |
  |                                   creates a temporary value which is freed while still in use
9 |     some_fut.await;
  |     -------- borrow later used here
  |
  = note: consider using a `let` binding to create a longer lived value
```

See [Temporary scopes](https://rustwiki.org/en/reference/destructors.html#temporary-scopes).

So you would only need to use a separate variable if the reference needs to be used beyond the statement for which it was created. Like in the above example or if `some_async_fn` returned some reference bound to the passed reference. The function being `async` is not really a factor.